# In dplyr, how to use a value in a column to specify another column to index

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, lubridate, mutated

I have data in the form of a list of objects (settings from our analysis machine). Some objects in the list are times, stored as a list containing hours, minutes and seconds.

I then have a 'directory', which contains the names of the objects in the data list.

I would like to add a column to the 'directory', and when the data type is 'time' I'd like it to insert the time in hh:mm:ss.

Here is an example of the data table:

```
data.times <- list(RUNT.1 = list(hour = 17L, minute = 48L, second = 56L, hsecond = 0L), 
    RUNT.2 = list(hour = 19L, minute = 0L, second = 47L, hsecond = 0L), 
    RUNT.3 = list(hour = 18L, minute = 19L, second = 8L, hsecond = 0L), 
    RUNT.4 = list(hour = 19L, minute = 0L, second = 48L, hsecond = 0L))
```

Here is an example of the 'directory' table

```
directory.times <- structure(list(data_label = c("RUNT.1", "RUNT.2", "RUNT.3", "RUNT.4"
), abif_type = c("time", "time", "time", "time"), description = c("Run start time", 
"Run stop time", "Data Collection start time", "Data Collection stop time"
), value = list(RUNT.1 = list(hour = 17L, minute = 48L, second = 56L, 
    hsecond = 0L), RUNT.2 = list(hour = 19L, minute = 0L, second = 47L, 
    hsecond = 0L), RUNT.3 = list(hour = 18L, minute = 19L, second = 8L, 
    hsecond = 0L), RUNT.4 = list(hour = 19L, minute = 0L, second = 48L, 
    hsecond = 0L))), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

If I wanted to pull out one specific time, I could easily do this:

```
library(lubridate)
  hms(paste(data.times[["RUNT.1"]][["hour"]],
            data.times[["RUNT.1"]][["minute"]],
            data.times[["RUNT.1"]][["second"]],
            sep=":"))
```

But I want to do this using dplyr, but it keeps erroring:

```
time.entry <- directory.times %>%
    mutate(time = case_when(abif_type == "time" ~
                              hms(paste(data.times[[paste0(data_label)]]["hour"],
                                        data.times[[paste0(data_label)]]["minute"],
                                        data.times[[paste0(data_label)]]["second"],
                                        sep="-"))))
```

The error is:

```
no such index at level 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may all get much easier if we work with a data.frame and convert the time elements to hms beforehand. The example data can be transformed into data.frame without any loss, not so sure with the actual data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
libary(purrr)
library(lubridate)

data.times <- data.times %>%
              map_dfr(~.x) %>%
              mutate(index = names(data.times), .before = everything()) %>%
              unite(col = time, c(hour, minute, second), sep = ':') %>% 
              mutate(time = hms(time))
data.times

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  index  time        hsecond
  <chr>  <Period>      <int>
1 RUNT.1 17H 48M 56S       0
2 RUNT.2 19H 0M 47S        0
3 RUNT.3 18H 19M 8S        0
4 RUNT.4 19H 0M 48S        0
```

I think you may pick it up from here